# How to restrict public access to uploads folder in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a custom backend ASP.NET MVC 4 application, that allows the users to upload student documents, transcripts, etc. I need to know how I can restrict public access to the uploads folder, but still be able to upload files to in, from within my application.

Is this something that would be handled on a directory level, within IIS?

I'm not sure how to go about this, as most of my experience is with Apache and .htaccess files, which make this easy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict public access to the folder by adding **authorization** in web.config. You simply replace the allow/deny with your own rules. For example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator" />
            <allow roles="Sales Representative" />
            <deny roles="Sales Manager" />
            <deny users="*" />
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now if you want to deny access to your IIS directory, please check this ([Deny access to directory in IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101371/deny-access-to-directory-in-iis-6-0))

I hope it helps you.